# Unable to initialise a Docker contained API server database

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, docker

> The goal is to set up the Bullet Train API server running on local servers. I'm completely new to dockerization, so need some help

As per the docs at [Bullet Train API server](https://github.com/BulletTrainHQ/bullet-train-api) which I have cloned on my local machine.

When I run `docker-compose build` & `docker-compose up` on my local machine, the server **seems to be** up and running.

However, I get this warning:

[image: PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization]

When I search the code, I can't see this string anywhere in the code. *How is this even possible?*

I have some questions here:

- How do I force this docker container to initialize the database?
- What is causing this skip of database initialization?

Comment: mmmh have u try docker-compose build ?